# Matching and removing rows in a matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, rows

Suppose I have a matrix ssout (10x14)

```
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04312609959835    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  10000   0.00100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04246490864522    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  10000   0.0100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04286618115584    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  10000   0.100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04104656008947    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.00100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    6.00000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   1.99946261970354    9.04233762205933e-16    4.52116877247632e-16    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.00100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.25000000000000e-05    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   1.86355987378850    8.17630355003923e-15    4.08815174015873e-15    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.00100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04723993665275    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.0100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    6.00000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   1.99903967606786    9.04233762205933e-16    4.52116877247632e-16    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.0100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.25000000000000e-05    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   1.86368041811290    8.17630355003923e-15    4.08815174015873e-15    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.0100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1.50000000000000e-06    0.990000000000000   0.0900000000000000  3.45000000000000    1.10000000000000    1   2.04266773220586    1.41286525344677e-17    7.06432620699426e-18    0.0100000000000000  100000  0.100000000000000
```

I want to refine this matrix by eliminating the rows that have no other similar rows matching. The criteria here is that two rows match if the column [1:2 4:8 12:14] of those two rows are the same. For any one of the row, we delete it if there is no other rows that match to it base on our criteria.

I have code like this

```
ssout = sout;
rows = size(sout,1);
rowss = size(ssout,1);
c1 = 1:2
c2 = 4:8
c3 = 12:14
cout = 0

for i = 1: rows;
   for j = 1: rows-1;

       if isequal(sout(i,[c1 c2 c3]),ssout(j,[c1 c2 c3]));
           [i j]
           cout = cout +1 %increase cout each time it finds a match to row i
       end
       if cout < 2;%included comparison it to itself
           sout(i,:) = [];
           cout = 0;  %reset cout to 0     
           rows = size(sout,1); %update rows
       end

   end

end
```

I know something is wrong, but not sure how to make it work yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `unique` function with the `rows` option on `ssout(:,[1:2 4:8 12:14])` to get indexes of all the unique rows and then use the indexes to get only those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be much simpler to use `unique` to determine what rows should be included in the result rather than eliminating rows which are similar. Example:

```
[~ , idx] = unique(ssout(:,[1:2 4:8 12:14]),'rows') % Find index of all unique rows
ssout_filtered = ssout(idx,:);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know there is "unique" function. One more quick question, I try to sort the final matrix ssout_filtered by "ssout_filtered = sortrows(ssout_filtered,[1 2 4 5 6 7 12 13 14 3])." It did not sort column 14 as I demanded. Instead, it sorts column 3. Is there anything wrong?